# Replace NA with unknown

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to replace the `NA's` of column `GENDER_M` of `objeto1` dataframe.

Nothing of the following works:

```
replace_na(objeto1$GENDER_M, "unknown")

mutate(GENDER_M = replace_na(GENDER_M, "unknown"))

mutate(objeto1, GENDER_M = ifelse(is.na(GENDER_M), "unknown", GENDER_M))

replace(is.na(GENDER_M), "unknown")
```

Yes, I've read [this page](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tidyr/versions/0.8.3/topics/replace_na) and a dozen others.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I've tried objeto1<- replace_na(objeto1$GENDER_M, "unknown") and now objeto1 doesn't seem to be a dataframe anymore and it's totally fd'up

Comment: `replace_na` acts on a dataframe, you gave it a vector. Look at the `?replace_na` examples: you'd want to use it like `objecto1 <- replace_na(objecto1 , list(GENDER_M = 'unknown'))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the `tidyverse` functions return the modified data frame, they don't modify it in place, so you need to assign the value when you return it. If we make an example dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(mpg = c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, NA, NA), cyl = c(6, 
6, 4, 6, 8, 6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

   mpg cyl
1 21.0   6
2 21.0   6
3 22.8   4
4 21.4   6
5   NA   8
6   NA   6
```

We can replace NA in several ways:

```
df <- df %>%
    replace_na(list(mpg = 'unknown'))

df <- df %>%
    mutate(mpg = ifelse(is.na(mpg), 'unknown', mpg))
```

Both of which return the same thing:

```
df
      mpg cyl
1      21   6
2      21   6
3    22.8   4
4    21.4   6
5 unknown   8
6 unknown   6
```

You could also use base R:

```
df[is.na(df)] <- 'unknown'
```

---

**Beware:** there is a risk to this: Each variable in a data frame can only have one type (ie. `numeric`, `logical`, `character`). Adding `character` values to these variables will cause the whole variable to be converted to `character`, which may cause problems when trying to due numeric calculations in the future. This is why the special value `NA` is strongly preferred over other values for identifying missing data.

Comment: Ok, I've tried objeto1 <- objeto1 %>% mutate(GENDER_M = ifelse(is.na(GENDER_M), 'unknown', GENDER_M)) and summary(objeto1) is now returning for GENDER_M: Length:51609 Class :character   Mode  :character  and I'm not sure it worked. I hope it did, this trivial task should not take more than 10 secs.

Comment: It's tough to say any more without a reproducible example. If these examples don't work, it's likely because there's something unusual with your data or session. Without a reproducible example of your data, there's no way for me to do further troubleshooting